# vue and vue-material: how to start?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

After creating a fresh new project using `vue create`, I would like to integrate vue material, from `vuematerial.io`.

I installed, via npm, the package

```
npm install vue-material --save
```

But then when I reach the following instruction I don't know what to do

> It's optional, but to have the best experience possible, use Roboto and Google Icons from Google CDN:
>
> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?> 
>    family=Roboto:400,500,700,400italic|Material+Icons">
> ```

Where is supposed I add this line?

I've no .thtml file, I have a main.js, App.vue, HelloWorld.vue, but no .html.

How to integrate it with a base  .vue project?

Comment: I advise against using vue-material, I started with it and had to switch to Vuetify as the vue-material projects progress has all but halted and is incomplete.
www.vuetifyjs.com

Comment: _"Where is supposed I add this line?"_  typically in [`public/index.html`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-index-file)

Comment: @MarcNewton: last 1.0 beta has been release on 15 May 2018. I see your point and I'll try  www.vuetifyjs.com. Thanks a lot for your warning !!

Comment: I would also go with vuetify. Also packages Like vue-meta are around to change <head> dynamicly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Phil

I didn't see the `public/index.html`.